# NSDateFormatter return incorrect date from string

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a method,

```
+ (NSDate *) convertToDateFrom:(NSString *) dateString
{
    if (dateString == nil || [dateString isEqual:@""]) return nil; //return nil if dateString is empty
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"];

    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];

    return date;
}
```

When I pass,

```
@"Monday, 21 November 2011 17:01" //Passed string
```

It returns a wrong date,

```
2011-11-21 23:14:00 +0000 // Output
```

---

I am not sure whether I am using those flags correctly or NSDateFormatter isn't properly converting my string to date.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Well, first off it's returning the right date, just the wrong time.  If you really are feeding in 17:01 and getting back 23:14 then you're probably looking at the wrong NSDate object, since there's no reasonable timezone setting that will produce that offset.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `+0000` at the end of the date indicates GMT. All dates are stored relative to GMT; when you convert a date to a string or vice versa using a date formatter, the offset to your time zone is included. You can use NSDateFormatter's `-setTimeZone:` method to set the time zone used.

In short, you're not doing anything wrong in your code. Use `[df stringFromDate:date];` to see that the date is correct. (You can also use NSDate's `-descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:`.)

Comment: Seems like a bug when I asked descriptionWithLocale it dives me correct result, funny!

Comment: "description" (which you get by default if you just log the NSDate object as an object) shows you the UTC time.

Comment: I cant get exact time,but date is correct.I use this date for EkEvent and store event to default calendar in iPhone.In that case time does not matching.Please help me...

Comment: @user1980105 It's difficult to help in comments -- please post your own question with details of your situation and the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
df stringFromDate:date
```

Following worked on mine,

```
NSLog(@"Date for locale %@: %@",
      [[dateFormatter locale] localeIdentifier], [df stringFromDate:date]);
```

gave me output as :

```
Date for locale en_US: Wednesday, 26 June 2013 15:50
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the time zone and locale.

```
[df setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

Comment: I tried that but still it returns "2011-11-21 23:14:00 +0000"

Comment: If I may suggest some light reading:http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i

Comment: Seems like a bug when I asked descriptionWithLocale it gives me correct result, funny! result outcome was different between description and descriptionWitLocale...an hour difference :(

Comment: Unfortunately, Times and Dates are never easy, considering the time and date changes by location and then you've got daylight savings and leap years, nothing is constant with dates and times.