# NSDateFormatter not converting to correct date

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

I have a problem converting a string date to NSDate since the conversion is not correct. This is my code:

```
NSString *stringDate = @"6/20/2014 8:38:52 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *timeStamp = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
```

The log always says `TIMESTAMP: 2014-06-20 12:38:37 +0000`.

How can I convert it to a correct date? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the timezone setting (for the hour change)?

Comment: Are you using `NSLog()` (and therefore `[NSDate description]`) to display this date?  You should know, therefore, that that will display the date as GMT, and not the locale's time zone.

Comment: timezone is systemTimezone which is GMT + 8.

Comment: @SyncMnemosyne Hmmm, 20 = 12 + 8!  How are you displaying the date?

Comment: This happens again and again. NSDate has no time zone. It displays the date in UTC. Since your timezone is GMT + 8, the NSDate is absolutely correct. It was 12:38 around lunchtime in UTC time when you converted a date at 8:32 pm in your time zone. If you had called someone in London on the phone when you made that conversion and asked them for the time, they would have said "12:38" and that's the correct time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDateFormatter return incorrect date from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783667/nsdateformatter-return-incorrect-date-from-string)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are doing this to display the date in the log:

```
NSLog(@"timeStamp = %@", timeStamp);
```

Instead keep the date formatter around (store it globally or something) and do:

```
NSLog(@"timeStamp = %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timeStamp]);
```

The difference is the first line of code calls `[NSDate description]` to format the date, which uses UTC/GMT time zone, where as the second line of code uses the time zone configured in the date formatter (which by default is the same the locale's time zone), and crucially the same time zone you used to parse the string in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

And you get date in UTC time zone.

Comment: No, that doesn't get the correct time. It produces an NSDate that displays what the OP expects - but his expectations are wrong, and that date would be wrong.

Comment: +0000 - it's UTC time zone, if you want to get result date for other time zone, use for example [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT: 3600] - +0100

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this. It will give you proper output
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [dateComponents setYear:2014];
    [dateComponents setMonth:6];
    [dateComponents setDay:20];
    [dateComponents setHour:8];
    [dateComponents setMinute:38];
    [dateComponents setSecond:52];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

    //NSDate *timeStamp = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
    NSLog(@"date = %@",date);
//solutions[2247:70b] date = 2014-06-20 08:38:52 +0000 printing date
```